# Where I put Initial?

Tags: initialisms

What is first name,last name and middle name?

I have Big confusion..

Eg:   S.Dhanam

Here Dhanam is a girl name

Her father name Suresh.

How to Solve it?

Comment: Did you check any dictionary?

Comment: Yes, But not understand

Comment: What do you mean? If there's an initial, it can _only_ stand for the person's first name, since in English, all pre-nominals are two letters or more in length: _Mr., Mrs., Ms., Sir, Dr._, etc. Additionally, even in names, there is a space after that period (if the period is indeed included, which is often not necessary). _S. Dhanam_ can only mean "A person whose first name starts with 'S', and whose surname is 'Dhanam'" in English.

Comment: Are you Sure? Can i Implement for all places

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that any name and any initial are capitalised. Also, there must be a space between any name and any initial, and some people use a full stop/period after any initial(s). (I don't.) [EDIT: clarification - some people and some publishing companies don't space two (or more) initials together, with or without a full stop/period - J.K. Rowling, George HW Bush or GHW Bush - but it is much better to space them.]

I guess from the names in your example that you're Indian. Some time ago I read [the Wikipedia article on Indian names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_name), and remembered one particular peculiarity, which I have just found again:

'In Western, English-speaking societies, when there are two people with the same name, for example, Robert Jones and Robert Smith, in an elementary school class, they may be referred to as Robert J. and Robert S. respectively to avoid confusion. But two Ramans in Tamil Nadu have just the one name each. So the names of their fathers are used as initials instead of a surname. Raman, son of Gopal, would be G. Raman, and Raman, son of Dinesh, D. Raman.'

Are you from India; if so, what part of India, and is this the explanation you are looking for? If so, then the 'English' system of 'Christian/first/given name, middle name, surname/family name' may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in English, a person's father's or mother's name are not relevant for a person's own name.

The usual way a person's name is built up in English is as follows:
A person has a *family name*, or *surname*. This is usually the same as the surname of the father - but it can be the mother's as well. A common surname is, for instance, *Johnson*.

Then, a person's parents give the person one or more *given names*, also called *first names*. Whether a person is given one or more given names depends on many things, like religion, (family) tradition, etcetera. Common given names are *John*, *Paul*, *George* and *Ringo* (not really, that last one).

A person is often addressed by just one of his given names, in formal settings followed by his surname. In some places it is common to include the first letter(s) of the *other* given names in the "full name" as well.

So let's say that Mr. and Mrs. Bush have a child. They decide to give the child the given names *George* *Herbert* *Walker*.

His name can and will appear in many ways, including:

- Bush, George Herbert Walker (in his passport, on official documents where the surname takes precedence).
- George Herbert Walker Bush (on official documents, e.g. where he signs them)
- George (this is the way family and friends will normally address him).
- George Bush (in semi-formal settings where the full name is used to distinguish him from other Georges. Used in the press to refer to him.)
- G.H.W. Bush (for instance on a list, or an on-line form)
- George H. W. Bush (In formal settings or in the press, especially when it was needed to distinguish him from George W. Bush, his son).

This is far from complete - actually, naming conventions differ per country, per religion, per language, per culture; they change over time, and there are actually very few (if any) rules that can really be applied universally about names.
What I described is a common way of naming in a lot of English-speaking countries, but don't assume everyone does the same.